# How to replace duplicate occurrences of a variable in a string?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, string, echo

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
DIV='_'
STRING=’1__2__3__4__5'

echo $STRING
```

The result is:

```
1__2__3__4__5
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
1_2_3_4_5
```

Since this is a snippet of a larger codebase, I cannot edit `$STRING` directly to remove the duplicated dashes.

I have tried the following:

```
echo ${STRING//$DIV$DIV/$DIV}

echo $STRING | sed -E "s/$DIV$DIV/$DIV/g"
```

but the result is still:

```
1__2__3__4__5
```

I cannot use `_` instead of `$DIV` in the replacement commands since `$DIV` needs to be able to be changed, but `$STRING` will always have its numbers separated by 2 instances of whatever `$DIV` is.

Comment: Note you have a curly quote in your example which is not a valid quote character for the shell

Comment: Both of the things you have tried should have worked by the way so you probably have something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr`:

```
div=_
string=1__2__3__4__5

printf '%s\n' "$string" | tr -s -- "$div"
```

> -s, --squeeze-repeats
>
> > replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the last specified SET, with a single occurrence of that character

---

Using ksh93-style shell parameter expansion (requires `extglob` with `bash`):

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' "${string//+("$div")/$div}"
```

This will match a pattern of one or more `_` and replace them with a single `_`

Comment: That is a beautifully elegant solution that I will have to remember for next time. Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I should mention that $STRING contains several ANSI color codes, this does not show up when running the command, the appropriate colors are just used. When I am running the replace command, should I also be matching for the color codes?

Comment: The full codebase is at https://github.com/SxC97/Yabai-Spaces/blob/master/yabai.1d.sh if you are interested in looking at it.

Comment: @user3613167 there's nothing magic about color codes, they're just characters like any other characters. If your `STRING` has other characters than those shown in your question then edit your question to show them. You can use `echo "$STRING" | cat -v` to see/capture them in your terminal or just make them up or copy/paste them from your script that's populating STRING - what's most important is that there **are** characters somewhere, as opposed to there being no characters.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you to get the expected result

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.4.20

string="1__2__3__4__5" ; echo "${string//__/_}"
```

Tested on : https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler